# Can I use validation feature of Entity Framework in ASP.NET WEB FORMS

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, validation, webforms, ef-code-first

Can I use Entity Framework DbContext, Code First approach, Data Annotation validation and customize validation in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Data Annotations present in [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) with ASP.NET WebForms but only with the new ASP.NET 4.5.

Check this awesome tutorial for complete details:

[What's New in Web Forms in ASP.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetwebforms45.aspx)

[Exercise 2: Data Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetwebforms45_topic3)

There's also a NugGet package that seems to do what you want:

[Data Annotations Validator Control for ASP.NET Web Forms](http://nuget.org/packages/DAValidation)

Comment: No,i want use in asp.net web forms UI and NOT in Dynamic Data and MVC,now answer i can use it ???

Comment: `DbContext` and Fluent API configuration are parts of EntityFramework and so they're available out of the box. More on this here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-221c01f5 See the part "Entity Framework Code First, LocalDB" and "Data Annotations"...

Comment: As a result,can't use it in asp.net web forms,but can use in Dynamic Data and MVC,this correct?

Comment: No. You can use them in ASP.NET Web Forms as per the links I provided above.

Comment: thanks,My purpose from this question is too use Error message parameter of fluent api and validation api and show this Error message in client ui,this is possible???

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will be supported in ASP.NET 4. But in the mean time, you can use [xVal for WebForms](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/). There are [examples](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage&referringTitle=Documentation) and a [demo](http://xvalwebforms.apphb.com/) available online.

(disclaimer: this is one of my open source projects)